# How to feed multiple commands (from a text file) through command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was wondering if its possible to execute a command e.g. start xxxxxxx

where xxxxxxx is fed from a text file, so for example if the text file contained:

```
notepad
calc
putty
```

The following would be output in cmd:

```
start notepad
start calc
start putty
```

Can anyone let me know the easiest way to do this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is called cmds.lst, a batch file containing

```
for /f %%a in (cmds.lst) do start %%a
```

should do the trick